# Pagination with the same indexes of items in two pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pagination

Is it possible calculate two pages with the same indexes of items. Because I have a big table and I need to split it to left and right page. Left and right page have to have the same indexes of items. It's needed to split it, because it will be printing to pdf.

```
Example:
itemsPerPage = 5
totalItems = 16
totalPages = 8
__________________
page: indexOfItems
__________________
0: 0,1,2,3,4
1: 0,1,2,3,4
2: 5,6,7,8,9
3: 5,6,7,8,9
4: 10,11,12,13,14
5: 10,11,12,13,14
6: 15
7: 15
```

```
This should be console written:
_______________________________
"Current page 0: 0 - 4."
"Current page 1: 0 - 4."
"Current page 2: 5 - 9."
"Current page 3: 5 - 9."
"Current page 4: 10 - 14."
"Current page 5: 10 - 14."
"Current page 6: 15 - 15."
"Current page 7: 15 - 15."
```

```
const paginate = (totalItems: number, currentPage: number, pageSize: number) => {
  let startIndex: number = 0;
  let endIndex: number = 0;
  if (currentPage % 2 === 0) {
    // even page
    startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
    endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);
  } else {
    // odd page
    startIndex = (currentPage) * pageSize;
    endIndex = (currentPage * itemsPerPage) < totalItems ? (currentPage * itemsPerPage) : totalItems;
  }
  return {
    totalItems: totalItems,
    currentPage: currentPage,
    itemsPerPage: pageSize,
    startIndex: startIndex,
    endIndex: endIndex
  };
}

const numberOfItems:number = 16;
const itemsPerPage:number = 5;
const numberOfPages:number = Math.ceil(numberOfItems / itemsPerPage) * 2;

let pg: any = {};
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
  pg = paginate(numberOfItems, i, itemsPerPage);
  console.log(`Current page ${pg.currentPage}: ${pg.startIndex} - ${pg.endIndex}.`)
  // next code...
}
```

Any idea for algorithm?

Comment: Not much react here

Comment: I really wanted to help but I'm not sure I understand what you need

Comment: Each page has some items(rows). Each item(row) has an index. One item(row) has for example 20 collumns. For simplicity, 16 items will come from the database and they have to be arranged in a pdf file. One pdf page should have max 5 items(rows). Left pdf page will have 10 columns, right pdf page will have 10 columns. In one pdf page fit 5 items(rows) with 10 columns. Left part of item(row) to first page. Right part of item(row) to second page. I hope it's clearer.

Comment: I need to print table to pdf. Table is so wide, therefore it's needed split table to left part and right part to two pdf pages. I agree, pdf has no concept of left or right or columns or rows, therefore I need to create somehow it.